# How set time for validation message on HTML5 form required attribute?

Tags: html, validation

I am using HTML5. On form validation, the message will be shown for about 5 seconds.
How to change it to be visible for 10 seconds?

```html
<form>
<input name="name" required />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI is implemented by the browser and isn't customisable. Different browsers will implement it differently. (e.g. when I test it, the message is displayed until I interact with the page again).